# Debugging protractor tests from the console

Tags: node.js, debugging, protractor

I have a protractor test run via gulp-protractor. How can I debug this test using the command line (for example via the node debugger)?

Is there a configuration option for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently (as of Protractor 5.0.0) the recommended way to do this has become `browser.enterRepl()`.

Comment: Note when you run this command look at your command prompt and you will see you can input protractor commands.  E.G. `element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText()`.  Then you can exit with `CTRL + C`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from protractor documentation:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

`browser.debugger()` and `browser.pause()` should be help.